# перевод Numpy NDAarray в JPEG в памяти

Tags: python, numpy, обработка-изображений

у меня есть изображение в виде ndarray, я хочу получить его в виде jpeg, но не сохраняя, а сохраняя в переменную.

Не хочу сохранять никакие данные в отдельный файл, я хочу просто сохранить jpeg представление в переменную, чтобы потом использовать это для запроса на сервер, который требует такой формат данных, отсюда и вопрос: как сделать подобное преобразование без создания отдельного файла? Как я могу реализовать это?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659312/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-to-and-display-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Фактически соответствующий ndarray и есть картинка, которую можно сохранить на диск в необходимом вам формате.

Пример:

```
import io
from imageio import imwrite

with io.BytesIO() as out:
    imwrite(out, img_array, format="JPEG")
    img_contents = out.getvalue()
```

Comment: да, писал быстро, выразился некорректно. Имел ввиду, что не хочу сохранять никакие данные в отдельный файл, я хочу просто сохранить jpeg представление в переменную, чтобы потом использовать это для запроса на сервер, который требует такой формат данных, отсюда и вопрос: как сделать подобное преобразование без создания отдельного файла